Access to fetch at 'https://js.stripe.com' has been blocked by CORS policy
I was writing a serverless React function that perform payments using Stripe. I've successfully installed all stripe dependencies with stripe CLI like dotenv to unable use of .env to store Secret Key and Public Key.
When I click on Pay Now button to process payment, it doesn't allow to process payment due to that CORS has blocked.
here is the image of errorenter image description here
Someone with the idea to solve this may help.
I have tried this in Payment-form.component.js
import { useState } from "react";
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

import { selectCurrentUser } from "../../store/user/user.selector";
import { selectCartTotal } from "../../store/cart/cart.selector";

import { BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES } from "../button/button.component";
import {
  PaymentFormContainer,
  FormContainer,
  PaymentButton,
} from "./payment-form.styles";

const PaymentForm = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const amount = useSelector(selectCartTotal);
  const currentUser = useSelector(selectCurrentUser);
  const [isIsProcessingPayment, setIsProcessingPayment] = useState(false);

  const paymentHandler = async (e) => {
    // Pevent typical form to be submitted
    e.preventDefault();

    // Making sure that the above two hooks are loaded in when payment handler fired
    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      return;
    }
    // setting processing payment to true when it stats to process payments

    setIsProcessingPayment(true);

    // Request to get the payment
    const response = await fetch("/.netlify/functions/create-payment-intent", {
      method: "post",
      //request: "no-cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ amount: amount * 100 }),
    }).then((res) => res.json());

    const {
      paymentIntent: { client_secret },
    } = response;

    const paymentResult = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        billing_details: {
          name: currentUser ? currentUser.displayName : "Guest",
        },
      },
    });

    // set processing payments to false when it ends to process
    setIsProcessingPayment(false);

    if (paymentResult.error) {
      alert(paymentResult.error);
    } else {
      if (paymentResult.paymentIntent.status === "succeeded") {
        alert("Payment Successfull");
      }
    }
  };

return (
    <PaymentFormContainer>
      <FormContainer onSubmit={paymentHandler}>
        <h2>Credit Card Payment: </h2>
        <CardElement />
        <PaymentButton
          isLoading={isIsProcessingPayment}
          buttonType={BUTTON_TYPE_CLASSES.inverted}
        >
          Pay Now
        </PaymentButton>
      </FormContainer>
    </PaymentFormContainer>
  );
};

export default PaymentForm;


And in the other component which is a serverless function named create-payment-intent.js, I wrote it as follow
create-payment-intent.js
require("dotenv").config();
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const { amount } = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency: "usd",
      payment_method_types: ["card"],
    });

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ paymentIntent }),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ error });

    return {
      status: 400,
      body: JSON.stringify({ error }),
    };
  }
};


Based on your error message it seems like maybe you have some Kaspersky browser extension installed that's interfering in some of the internal request the Stripe library is making. I'd suggest testing this in a fresh browser with no extensions/an incognito window to see if that helps.

No, I don't have any Kaspesky relate extension. I even toggled all extension off to see if the problem rget resolved but it is still the same error.

Even in incognito mode it is showing these errors. don't see what's really causing errors
